# Is there a way to change the keyboard shortcuts for an application in OSX?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like to know if it's possible to change the key bindings for menu selections in OS X? In particular, when I'm using Firefox and I want to bring up the Network developer tools panel, the keyboard shortcut is Command-Option-Q. Of course, the keyboard shortcut for Quit is Command-Q, so occasionally I end up quitting Firefox instead of opening the panel.

I assume there are add-ons that can do this, but I'm hoping there's a way to change this without the overhead of an add-on. (Or also a way that works more generally in OS X.) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Control Panel, choose Keyboard and Shortcuts.
Click the '+' sign, choose your application (Firefox for example) and type the exact name of the shortcut you want to change and enter the shortcut you want to use.

That's it.